# A strange python unicode decode error trying to do redis dump (prefer python3, but seeing in both 2 & 3))

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I am trying to do a `redis` dump using the python package [`redis-dump-load`](https://github.com/p/redis-dump-load).

It is in `UTF-8`, except for apparently one key, which I'm being told is in `ascii`. No idea why, but I thought, ok, if there is a `UnicodeDecodeError` for this one key (I am receiving lots of data from the dump stream up to this point), what I will do is get the encoding of the bytes string I have, and decode with that instead.

However, I am still getting a `UnicodeDecodeError` for `ASCII` as well! It is `bytes`, it is `ascii`, I think it might just be corrupt and I plan to just skip it, but curious if anyone had any other ideas.

This is my code snippet:

```
value = {}
for k in response:
    try:
        value[k.decode(encoding)] = response[k].decode(encoding)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print("Error for", k)
        print(type(k))
        orig_encoding = chardet.detect(k)['encoding']
        print(orig_encoding)
        value[k.decode(orig_encoding)] = response[k].decode(orig_encoding)
return value
```

And here is the ouput I see:

```
Error for b'meta'
<class 'bytes'>
ascii
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redisdl.py", line 243, in handle_response
    value[k.decode(encoding)] = response[k].decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redisdl.py", line 635, in <module>
    main()
  File "redisdl.py", line 626, in main
    do_dump(options)
  File "redisdl.py", line 547, in do_dump
    dump(output, **kwargs)
  File "redisdl.py", line 174, in dump
    for key, type, ttl, value in _reader(r, pretty, encoding, keys):
  File "redisdl.py", line 293, in _reader
    type, ttl, value = _read_key(encoded_key, r, pretty, encoding)
  File "redisdl.py", line 284, in _read_key
    value = reader.handle_response(results[2], pretty, encoding)
  File "redisdl.py", line 250, in handle_response
    response[k].decode(orig_encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Am I missing something? I have looked at multiple SO answers, believe me, and I thought up until now I understood `str`, `bytes`, decoding, and encoding. But maybe not. Even `py2` & `py3` differences I get. I think. Starting to doubt everything...

Comment: Ok the error says that the problem is not in the key: `b'meta'` can successfully be decoded in utf8 since it is plain ascii. So the problem comes from `response['meta']` which starts with a `0x80` byte. You should either look directly in original data what should be the `response` or print (or do an hex dump of) it in the except block.

Comment: Oh I see it now! Perhaps the response value is  in utf8 then. This was a silly question, thanks so much for the insight. Forest for the trees and all that I think!

Comment: So the key was in ASCII, and the value was in Windows-1254. Go figure. Fixed hopefully, thanks big time @SergeBallesta